# c++ : how can i overload < operator correctly?

Tags: c++, set

I need a `std::set<std::pair<int,NodeA>>`. So i need to overload the < operator of NodeA. I did it, but it doesn't work.

```
void matriceLab::aStar(int* matX,const int x, const int y, const int endX,const int endY){
    std::set<std::pair<int,NodeA>> nodi;
    allocaNodi(nodi,matX,x,y,endX,endY);


}
void matriceLab::allocaNodi(std::set<std::pair<int,NodeA>>& nodi, int* matX,const int x, const int y,const int endX,const int endY){
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j = j + 2){
            NodeA nodo(i,j,endX,endY);
            std::pair <int,NodeA> pair1(i + j * x, nodo);
            nodi.insert(pair1);
        }
    }
}

class NodeA
{
//...
       bool operator<(const NodeA& a){
            if(posX < a.posX){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
//...
}
```

> C:\TDM-GCC-32\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h|222|error:
>   no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const NodeA' and 'const
>   NodeA')|
>
> C:\Users\cristina\Desktop\università pdf\Laboratorio di Programmazione\progetti
>   c++_SFML_openGL\SFML-2019-4-Grid\NodeA.h|24|note: candidate: bool
>   NodeA::operator<(const NodeA&) << near match>>

Comment: `bool operator<(const NodeA& a) {` -> `bool operator<(const NodeA& a) const {`?

Comment: [Tangent] If you use `if(condition) return true; else return false;` just use `return condition;` instead.

Comment: *Why* do you need this set? What is is to be used for? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Perhaps there are better solutions?

Comment: The type you are using for `std::set` and the way you insert into it makes it seem as if you really want a `std::map` or `std::vector`. You have not shown how it is used, though, so I cannot be sure.

Comment: Does your `operator<` need to modify the object?  If not, is your `operator<` marked as `const`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

This reference says that as a **member function**, `operator<` has the format:

```
bool T::operator <(const T2 &b) const;
```

You need to mark your operator definition `const` since C++ wants you to promise that a mere `<` operator will not change the object(s) involved and will work with instances of the class that are declared `const`.

So you are missing the keyword `const` in the operator's overloading function. You will have to write:

```
bool operator<(const NodeA& a) const{
        if(posX < a.posX){ ...
```

If you are interested in knowing where exactly does c++'s code mention this, you can take a look at this StackOverFlow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23927045/7865858