# error C2678: no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty'

Tags: c++, c++17

I get the error:

`1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstddef(127,1): error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`
when i run my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstring>
#include <queue>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class grid {
private:
public:
    vector<vector<short> > tiles;

    grid()
    {
        tiles.resize(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            tiles[i].resize(4);
    }

    inline bool operator==(grid& b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                if (tiles[i][j] != b.tiles[i][j])
                    return false;
        return true;
    }

    inline bool operator<(const grid& b)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void shiftUp()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    if (tiles[j][i] == 0)
                        swap(tiles[j][i], tiles[j + 1][i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (tiles[j][i] == tiles[j + 1][i])
                {
                    tiles[j][i] *= 2, tiles[j + 1][i] = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    if (tiles[j][i] == 0)
                        swap(tiles[j][i], tiles[j + 1][i]);
    }
};

map<grid, bool> used;

bool exists(grid x)
{
    return used[x];
}

int main()
{
    grid x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cin >> x.tiles[i][j];

    x.shiftUp();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << x.tiles[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019. I've tried adding dummy '<' operators to the class and haven't found any other threads that worked for me.

Comment: Unrelated: `inline` is implicit for functions defined inside the class definition, so yours are unnecessary. (It has nothing to do with the inlining of function calls.)

Comment: Your comparision operator is not const, but it needs to be.

Comment: `operator<` should be `const` (and so should `operator==`).

Comment: [Why overloaded ' operator < ' should be const for class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927003/why-overloaded-operator-should-be-const-for-class)

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` uses by default `std::less` for comparision, which uses by default `operator <`. So you are correct to implement that operator.

However, the error suggests that there is no `operator <` taking a ***`const`*** left hand side. You need a const version:

```
class grid {
    // ...
    bool operator < (const grid &o) const { // Note *const* at end
        // Do something meaningful here
    }
}
```

Read about const-correctness (e.g. [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)).

Also note that the operator < needs to provide a strict weak ordering, so that if `a < b == true`, it must be that `b < a == false`

Comment: `map` only needs a strict weak ordering, not a total ordering.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's the thing I was not sure about, Fixed it. But `return false` is certainly wrong

Comment: That is the weakest ordering. It means that no element is ordered before any other – in other words, that all elements are equivalent. It's not formally wrong, but usually not very useful. `return true` would be very wrong.